# How to interpret results of `last reboot` command?

Tags: boot, log, gnome-activity-journal

I was supposed to left my device always on since Monday

```
last reboot
```

give me

```
 reboot   system boot  4.4.0-98-generic Wed Dec  6 08:52   still running
 reboot   system boot  4.4.0-98-generic Mon Dec  4 09:40 - 18:12 (1+08:31)
```

is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `man last`:

> last  searches  back  through  the  /var/log/wtmp file (or the file designated by the -f option) and displays a list of all users logged in (and out)
>          since that file was created.  One or more usernames and/or ttys can be given, in which case last will show only the entries matching those arguments.
>          Names of ttys can be abbreviated, thus last 0 is the same as last tty0.

For your command `last reboot`:

> The pseudo user reboot logs in each time the system is rebooted. Thus last reboot will show a log of all the reboots since the log file was created.

Shows you number of reboots the system went through, and reboot and shutdown are pseudo-users for system reboot and shutdown, respectively.

Comment: i don't understand why 2 rows and not a one? i'm only user of system. Ok. i have to consult famous man.

Comment: How many times have you reboot since log file was created, and is this a fresh install? Mine is 13 lines and I am the only user!

Comment: one  time.   Monday

Comment: fresh install? no, this is ubuntu re-cloned by clonezilla. from one hdd to other. i have no problem i believe i m fine

Comment: one strange - uname -r
4.4.0-98-generic
at boot time grub show  101 kernel

Comment: ok. i accept the answer. thus my question is a bit to wide